# How highlight and save selected text in UIwebview using Coregraphics

Tags: ipad, uiwebview, core-graphics, highlighting, epub

How to make persistent Highlight on UIWebView (containing epub contents) so that he can view it whenever he come to that page. What I came to conclusion that I succeeded in getting the index of the selected text which I could save in database.

What I need to create a transparent rectangle sort of thing using graphics from starting to end index. But how to know the coordinates of text so that I can draw rectangle on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inorder to make permanent highlight in epub add a span to the string you want to highlight then rewrite that HTML. Highlight would be preserved for ever

```
    NSString *uuid = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];

    NSString *insertSpan = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);var selectionContents   = range.extractContents();alert(selectionContents); var span                = document.createElement(\"span\");span.appendChild(selectionContents);span.setAttribute(\"class\",\"uiWebviewHighlight\");span.style.backgroundColor  = \"#99FF00\";span.setAttribute(\"id\", \"%@\");range.insertNode(span);",uuid];
   [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:insertSpan];

    NSString *document = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML"];

    NSData *data = [document dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

   [data writeToFile:currentChapter.spinePath atomically:YES];
```

Comment: @soniya were you able to create your epub with uipage view controller?If so can you share that idea

Answer (score 0):

```
function stylizeHighlightedString() 
{
     var range               = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
     var selectionContents   = range.extractContents();
     var span                = document.createElement("span");

     span.appendChild(selectionContents);
     span.setAttribute("class","uiWebviewHighlight");

     span.style.backgroundColor  = "red";
     span.style.color            = "white";

     range.insertNode(span);
}
```

Comment: I want highlighting a text permanently. I have sqlite to store any metadata.